# Simple WPF MVVM Commanding Issue - What's Wrong With This Code?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, icommand

I'm trying to set up a command on a button in my UI using MVVM. The command doesn't execute when I click the button, though. The code is based off of [Jason Dolinger's example](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650) (link in 3rd paragraph).

It seems like it should be pretty simple, so I'm sure I'll feel silly once I find out what's wrong.

Relevant code bits follow. The command is as follows (very simple):

```
public class NavigateCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Executed.");
    }
}
```

The XAML looks like:

```
<Button x:Name="btn_ProjectManager" Command="{Binding Navigate}" Content="Test Button">
```

The ViewModel looks like:

```
public class HomeScreenViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public ICommand Navigate;

    public HomeScreenViewModel()
    {
        this.Navigate = new NavigateCommand();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the view's datacontext?

Comment: Also, why is your viewmodel deriving from DependencyObject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Navigate` should be a property. Binding works only with properties

Comment: And make sure it's not an auto-property, i had trouble with those.

Comment: I'm really not sure, it might be a bug, happened to me in Silverlight.
auto property didn't work, when i made it a full property, it did.

Comment: @Snowbear, I tried changing "public ICommand Navigate" to "public ICommand Navigate { get; set; }", but it didn't change the behavior any. :( Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: @Anthony, then maybe something wrong with your ViewModel-DataContext setup. Take a look at VS output window - probably there are binding errors there.

Comment: @Notter: Changing it to a public property backed by a private field didn't get me anywhere either.

Comment: @Snowbear: No errors of any sort in the Output window. To ensure that my DataContext was set up correctly, I added a string property to my ViewModel and bound it to a TextBox on the screen--it worked, so evidently that's okay.

Comment: @Notter, there is no difference between an auto-prop and one with a backing field.  An auto-prop is compiled into a normal property with a backing field anyway.

Comment: @Anthony: I just tested your code exactly as written except replacing `Navigate;` with `Navigate { get; set; }` as @Snowbear suggests.  It works as expected and the message box is shown.